# Apache Royale : How to detect enter key on j:textInput

Tags: keyboard-events, textinput, apache-royale

I have this code :

```
<j:TextInput localId="ti_pass"  >
    <j:beads><j:PasswordInput/></j:beads>
</j:TextInput>
```

Unfortunaly looking at https://apache.github.io/royale-docs/component-sets/jewel/textinput I didn't find a bead for KeyDown event.
Is there a specific event to listen for it ?

Is there a way to know if enter key has been hit ?

Thanks Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say that there's a better solution to your problem, but I completely forgot due to focus on keydown. Sorry.

You have an `enter` event in TextInput that you can use directly. Example is in Tour De Jewel in TextInputPlayGround.

```
private function enterPress(event:Event):void
{
    trace("enter pressed");
}
```

```xml
<j:TextInput text="A TextInput" enter="enterPress(event)"/>
```

HTH

Carlos

Comment: Thanks, effectively that's better !
Note on your previous post (which is also very interessing), it's event.type to be tested for 'KeyDown' (not event.key)

Comment: Right, I was confused and thinking you were referring to "arrow down key" ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to listen for `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` on the strand (TextInput).

If you are in MXML, first add a listener for `initComplete` in the surrounding container for `listenKeyDown`:

```
initComplete="listenKeyDown()"
```

Then in the Script part add:

```
public function listenKeyDown():void {
    the_textinput.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownEventHandler)
}

protected function keyDownEventHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace("Any key:", event.key);

    if(event.key === KeyboardEvent.KEYCODE__DOWN)
    {
        trace("Down key:", event.key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I little fix code to done it working.

Comment: More over, does I need take care of using removeEventlistener ? (I will open a new SOF on it)

Comment: you need to remove listeners as usual. If you adding/removing components that are listening to other parts of the app, be sure to maintain the listeners to avoid leaks